# Project config issues how to specify a unique - kwcc_config.xml for each project?

Tags: c, klocwork

The file kwcc_config.xml contains definitions and include paths for specific compilers used by our projects.

Due to our different environments for different projects we need different definitions and paths for the projects.

Is there an option to define such file per project? If so, how do I assign kwcc_config.xml file for each project?

Answer (score 0):

kiamlaluno,

This file is not associated with a project, it is global per installation. It can contain entries for multiple compilers though.

The compiler are identified by the full path. So if different projects use different compilers (hence different default settings) you should introduce a separate section in the kwcc_config.xml.

Like this:

```
<configurations>
  <configuration>
     <compiler path="/path/to/your/compiler"/>
     ......
   </configuration>
</configurations>
```

But generally, most of the compilers should be configured automatically, hence not requiring editing kwcc_config.xml.

What compilers do you use?

Comment: Mostly gcc & g++ versions. For Klocwork we swapped the different versions of gcc & g++ to one fixed compiler (some gnu gcc). As a result, paths for other compiler libraries became non referenced. 
This might be a good solution. Thanks, Moshe.

Comment: Yet, If we have some projects that use some compilers and other projects that don't use it - can we prevent the other project from looking up files in compilers not used by the list of their's ?
Thanks, Moshe.